# How to save ajax request data into different variables

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to store the data that comes back from an ajax call into different variables.

**Ajax Call**

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'fetch_lat_lng.php',
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: "html",    
  success: function(data) {
    //called when successful

    //lat = php lat variable
    //lng = php lng variable 

    myvar = data;
    console.log(lng);

    $('#ajaxphp-results').html(data);
  }
});
```

**fetch_lat_lng.php**

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = 636 ";
$result = query($query);
confirmQuery($result);


while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

    $lat = $row['lat'];
    $lng = $row['lng'];

}

echo $lat. " ". $lng;
```

I would like to save the php variables $lat and $lng into javascript variables in the ajax call. Is this possible to do?

Looking forward for your answers, thank you!

Kind Regards,

Comment: Use `json_encode` function.

Comment: ehat woulkd you like to happen if db returns more than one row, store only the last results or all of them? it is not clear

Comment: or no rows for that matter

Comment: $lat and $lng needs to be saved into javascript variables with an ajax call so I can use them in my javacscript file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your server-side code to following

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = 636 ";
$result = query($query);
confirmQuery($result);


while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

    $lat = $row['lat'];
    $lng = $row['lng'];

}
// Encode the output data
echo json_encode(array('latitude'=>$lat, 'longitude' => $lng));
?>
```

Change ajax call code to following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
  url: 'fetch_lat_lng.php',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    //called when successful
    latitude = data.latitude;
    longitude = data.longitude;
  }
});
</script>
```

If there is more longitude and latitude needs to be returned, update the output structure as per your requirement.

**Example:**

```
 <?php
// Decode the output data
echo json_encode(
    array(
        0 =>
        array(
            'latitude'=>12, 'longitude' => 34
        ),
        1 =>
        array(
            'latitude'=>56, 'longitude' => 78
        ),
    )
);
?>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: With `dataType: "json"` there's no need to use `JSON.parse`

Comment: what if the db returns more than one row? it is not clear what should happen then, store all lat/lngs?

Comment: @NikosM. I've changed the query so I get every lat and lng from the user in the table. I would like to show all of this in the console.log. Do I need to make a foreach loop?

Comment: console the output and iterate the data by checking the output.

Comment: @Nikhil It gives back:Object {lattitiude: "0", longitude: "0"}  I changed the query to this: $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE ingelogd = 1 ";

Comment: Which means the data is not returning properly. Try to return some hardcoded values and see if it consoling the proper data.

Comment: @Nikhil When I now use console.log it gives me back 2 objects. The hardcoded above. So that does work. But the query gives back only the first result which is 0. I think I need to use a foreach or something like that.

Comment: That is something you need to do with the server-side code.

Comment: @Nikhil Thank you sir, you helped me alot! I really appreciate your time and help.

Comment: Don't need to call sir, glad to know it helped. Have a great day :-)

Comment: @Nikhil Hi Nikhil, I dare not to ask but can you help me out with the iteration on server side?

Answer (score 0):

On the PHP side:

```
<?php

    // Do all the things.
    // PS. Do a LIMIT 1 in the SQL query.
    // PPS. Maybe IF () instead of WHILE ().

    $response = [
        'lat' => $lat,
        'lon' => $lon
    ];
    header("Content-type: application/json");
    echo json_encode($response);
```

On the jQuery side:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'fetch_lat_lng.php',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data.lat, data.lon);
    }
});

// PS. "type" in your example should be method.
// PPS. "method": "GET" is the default, so no need for that.
// PPPS. You can use $.get("fetch_lat_lng.php", function (data) {}) instead of $.ajax.
```

Comment: note that this requires PHP 5.4+ else use `array(..)` instead of `[..]`

Answer (score 0):

Return your response from `PHP` in `json` encoded form like this:

```
$result['lat'] = $lat;
$result['lng'] = $lng;
echo json_encode($result);
```

**And in ajax request:**

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'fetch_lat_lng.php',
  type: 'GET', 
  dataType: "json",     // change dataType as well.
  success: function(data) {
    //called when successful

    console.log(data);
    var lat = data.lat;
    var lng = data.lng;

    console.log(lat);
    console.log(lng);

    //$('#ajaxphp-results').html(data);
  }
});
```

Note that, you must need to change the Data type for `json` encoded data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to do so. Use JSON as a datatype, which will let you save data in a javascript variable, like this :

```
$.ajax({
 url: 'fetch_lat_lng.php',
 type: 'POST',
 dataType: "json",    
 success: function(data) {
 var lat = data.lat;
 var lng = data.lng;
 //saved in javascript variable
  }
});
```

Encoding it in json format in fetch_lat_lng.php, this way :

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = 636 ";
$result = query($query);
confirmQuery($result);

$data = array();
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $data = array(
            "lat" => $row['lat'],
            "lng" => $row['lng']
            );
            $data[] = $data;
        }
echo json_encode($data);
```

That's it, Hope it helps.